# Getting 3.6V, 1.8V, and 1.1V from 12V using LM117 or LM317

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

Please all, I need some help in designing power lines for my project.
I intend to use one LM117 (or LM317) to have at least three voltage lines on my breadboard, i.e 3.6V, 1.8V and 1.1V from a 12V supply (all DC).

I used the following formula to try and get a 1.1V DC line.

$$ R_2=R_1 \left( \frac{V}{1.25}-1 \right) $$

The tutorial I read suggested a standard value for R1 to be 240 ohms, which leaves me with a negative value for R2 (and for some reason i think this is wrong), for example:

$$ \begin{align}
  R_2 &= 240 \left( \frac{1.1}{1.25} - 1 \right)\\
  R_2 &= -28.8
\end{align}$$

1. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Should I be using a different value for R1?
   For a background, I am trying to have three power lines of 3.6V, 1.8V and 1.1V from a 12V source (all DC) using the LM117/337
2. Can I have all three power lines off one LM117/317

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That regulator will not provide output voltages below 1.25V.

The device uses an internal 1.25V reference voltage and the output voltage (via R1 and R2) is potted down to equal 1.25V. If the desired output voltage is less than 1.25V then it doesn't work.

AD8605 op-amp regulator for supplying 30mA at 1.1V: -

[image]

Comment: Any suggestions on regulators that can give the voltage I want or indeed how to step down a 1.25V line to 1.1? Also, can I have the other two voltages off the single regulator

Comment: How much current do you need?

Comment: For the 1.1V i need 30mA

Comment: PS. Could you suggest a regulator that can offer my desired voltage range without having to fidget with the power lines of the LM117/317s?

Comment: I'd use an op-amp from the 3.6V rail - unity gain, non-inverting configuration with a potential divider from the 3.6V rail generating 1.1V at the non-inverting input. AD8605 springs to mind but there will be several that meet the spec i.e. will run from 2.7V to 5V (decent range) with rail-to-rail inputs and outputs.

Comment: @pekatete I've put a diagram on the answer

Comment: @pekatete If you only need 30mA maybe just use a simple resistive voltage divider, if you don't need good regulation.

Comment: Andy, thanks for all, I think that answers my question perfectly (and the diagram too, very handy). Not sure I marked the thread correctly, a bit counter intuitive having to vote for an answer by clicking the down arrow!)

Comment: Just the last part of my question then, can I have both the 3.6V and 1.8V traces off the same LM117/317?

Comment: One supply rail per regulator but if the 1.8V is also lowish current you can use the same sort of idea and use a dual version of the AD8605 = AD8606

Comment: Maybe also consider the LT3022 adjustable regulator